# What is the pie chart in Nautilus when copying for a widget

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pygobject, gtk4

I am developing a Python program with a GTK4 GUI and would like to use the pie chart which is also displayed in Nautilus when copying files etc.

Can anyone tell me if this is a standard GUI element and what it is called?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKz4i.png)

I would like to import many files into a database and display the progress in the header bar.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a standard GUI element, it is built from a Gtk.Button whose icon is changed over time to represent the progress of the operation.

When clicked, it displays a Gtk.Popup with a Gtk.Label, a Gtk.ProgressBar and another Gtk.Button inside.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34720075)